# Error creating bean in spring application because of @Value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have a class which is a component. In this class I am trying to populate a property from application.properties. I am using @Value annotation for the same.
When I am adding @value annotation it is throwing the below error. 
@Value on the setter method is causing the application to throw the `Injection of autowired dependencies failed;` exception.

Following is the Class:

```
@Component
public class AgsProbeConstants {

 public static final String COMPONENT_KEY = "component";
 public static final String API_KEY = "api";
 public static final String CALLEE_KEY = "callee";
 public static final String RESPONSE_CODE_KEY = "response_code";
 public static final String ERROR_RESPONSE_CODE_KEY = "error_reason_code";
 public static final String HOST_KEY = "host";
 public static final String METRIC_VALUE = "api.connect.http.count";

 public String pushUrl;

 public String getPushUrl() {
    return pushUrl;
 }

 @Value("${property.push.url}")
 public void setPushUrl(String url) {
    pushUrl = url;
 }
}
```

This perfectly works fine and picks the value when I am directly running the webApp. But when I am doing a maven install It throws error. Following is the error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'agsProbeConstants': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'property.push.url' in value "${property.push.url}"


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'property.push.url' in value "${property.push.url}"


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
```

Following is the Application.properties file:

```
server.port=8080
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet: DEBUG

spring.profiles.active=dev
# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=debug
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

Following is the Application-dev.properties

```
#DB settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://localhost:60020/DB
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://10.10.10.10:60020/DB        
use this for docker, if facing DNS resolution issue.
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "create-drop" the database
# schema will be automatically created afresh for every start of application
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
#schema setting for JPA
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=schema1
# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# Scheduler properties
#======================
property.map={VROL:'http://localhost:8080/availability/statuszz', VDP:'http://localhost:8080/availability/statuszz'}
property.push.url=http://localhost:4242/write
```

I am not able to figure out what is the problem. Why the maven build is failing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The fragments you show are too small to say something useful. Is the file loaded in any test? How and where do you configure `property.push.url`? The reason for

Comment: did you defineconfigure `property.push.url` in your `application.properties` file ?

Comment: When building tests are being run. An `@SpringBoot` based test will create all the beans and therefor needs proper confiugration. Create an `applicaiton.properties` for testing which contains all needed configuration.

Comment: I have added the properties file

Comment: _property.opera.push.url=http_ versus _@Value("${property.push.url}")_

Comment: @DirkDeyne that is same. Mistakenly I wrote wrong constant value here.

Comment: @IshanTiwary Do you have application.properties in your `src/test/resources` folder? It looks like when you have tests which are failing when trying to load the spring context. Add the application.properties to `src/test/resources` and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried same set of application.properties files in src/test/resources which were there in src/main/resources but its still the same.

Comment: @Ameen.M Tried doing that but that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Then your properties aren't read. make sure it is either in the main `application.properties` or you use `@ActiveProfile` to activate the proper profiles for testing.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks it worked when I used the Dev profile in `@ActiveProfile`